# How can i get my C# application on another computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a small C# application on my home computer using Visual Studio 2015 and Id like to use this small application on my computer at work.
Can someone point me to a tutorial/video to help me accomplish this? thanks.

Comment: I just copy the debug or release folder to whatever computer and run it from there.

Comment: Asking for links/guidance to off-site resources is considered off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for the heads up David L! sorry i do apologize for the off topic question. Im still new to the site and programming.

Comment: and thank you for the response Quantic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offtopic or not. I imagine this might be a problem for those who start using any programming language. As @Quantic mentions the quickest way is to actually copy the folder ./Release or ./Debug to the computer of your choise. You can also use the Oneclick https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated